# 64 bit Registry Key not updated by 32 bit application

Tags: c#

Registry Key is not updated at mentioned path in C#

```
string path = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\"; 
RegistryKey myKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);
myKey.SetValue("USERProcessHandleQuota", 50000, RegistryValueKind.DWord); 
myKey.Close();
```

instead of given path value update at below path :-

```
@"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\";
```

My machine is 64 bit and the application I am running is 32 bit.

Kindly suggest how to update value at above path address i.e in `Software\Microsoft` and not `Software\wow6432node`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways

- `RegistryView.Registry64` and `OpenBaseKey` in .Net 4 and above
- `RegOpenKeyEx` Api call in `Advapi32.dll` with the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag in earlier versions

> **RegistryView Enumeration** : On the 64-bit version of Windows, portions of the registry are stored
>   separately for 32-bit and 64-bit applications. There is a 32-bit view
>   for 32-bit applications and a 64-bit view for 64-bit applications.
>
> You can specify a registry view when you use the OpenBaseKey and
>   OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive, String, RegistryView) methods, and the
>   FromHandle property on a RegistryKey object.

**Code** using Registry64

```
using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
   using (var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey("blah", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl))
   {
      if (subKey != null)
      {
         var value =  subKey.GetValue("Somekey");
      }
   }
}
```

**PInvoke** using `RegOpenKeyEx` and `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` can be found here

[PInvoke RegOpenKeyEx (advapi32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/RegOpenKeyEx.html)

> **Note** : Both these should allow your 32 bit app to access the full
>   registry, not just the Wow6432Node registry redirector.

**Resources**

[RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey Method (RegistryHive, RegistryView)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RegistryKey.OpenSubKey Method (String, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck, RegistryRights)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128502(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RegistryView Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx)

[32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Only concern is after changing value in registry it updates the user process handle but the system requires a restart. Any way or method I can prevent that?

Comment: @mehtaankit, i think its something that windows reads on startup, im not sure you can get around the reboot. though im not 100% sure