# C# Winforms get int Value from registry

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int i = (Int32)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Beerbaum", "TCP_Listening_Delay", null);
      MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

In the Registry there is a **QWORD-Value(64-Bit)** called **TCP_Listening_Delay** and its value is **dec:5000**

When I press the button it should open a MessageBox which should display 5000, but it doesn't. All it does is giving me,

> "NullReferenceException was unhandled".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: For everybody who has the same Problem but no answer.
I used the code from @Saruman and changed the Propertys to `RegistryRights.ReadKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Registry.GetValue(String, String, Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_Registry_GetValue_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)

> Retrieves the value associated with the specified name, in the
>   specified registry key. If the name is not found in the specified key,
>   returns a default value that you provide, or null if the specified key
>   does not exist.

**Returns**

> `null` if the subkey specified by `keyName` does not exist; otherwise, the
>   value associated with `valueName`, **or `defaultValue` if `valueName` is not
>   found.**

However i think your problem is you are probably trying to read 64/32 bit registry hive from a 32/64 bit application

> RegistryView Enumeration : On the 64-bit version of Windows, portions
>   of the registry are stored separately for 32-bit and 64-bit
>   applications. There is a 32-bit view for 32-bit applications and a
>   64-bit view for 64-bit applications.
>
> You can specify a registry view when you use the OpenBaseKey and
>   OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive, String, RegistryView) methods, and the
>   FromHandle property on a RegistryKey object.

```
using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
   using (var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey("blah", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl))
   {
      if (subKey != null)
      {
         var value =  subKey.GetValue("Somekey");
      }
   }
}
```

[64 bit Registry Key not updated by 32 bit application](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148623/1612975)

Comment: Thanks but my Key is null and I don't know why